# Parse 2D Array in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I have created a 2D array named squareData as shown below:

```
 private lateinit var squareData: Array<Array<String>>

 squareData = Array(3, {Array(3, {""})})
```

Also, I initialized this array with some random values. Now I want to fetch this values one by one. How can I do it using for or forEachIndexed loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate in the array like this :

```
for (strings in squareData) {
    for (string in strings) {
        Your code here
    }
}
```

The first for iterate through the first dimension so it has string arrays and the second one through the second dimension so it has the string values

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular nested for loop.

```
for (arr in squareData) {
    for (s in arr) {
        println(s)
    }
}
```

You can iterate using `forEach`:

```
squareData.forEach { it.forEach(::println) }
```

or if you want index position as well, `forEachIndexed`:

```
squareData.forEachIndexed { i,it -> println(i); it.forEach(::println) }
```