# How do I compact these loops?

Tags: loops

I am written over 100 lines of code and I know there has to be a way to do this with less code. I want to check if the value in the double array equals "." and replace it with the user's input "X" or "O". Starting from the bottom as if they are pieces in a connect 4 game. I have written a loop for every column to search for the row. I haven't found a way to do it without changing every "." in that column. This is one column for one user.

```
         var gameBoard = Array(8){ Array(8){"."} }

         fun checkOneX( ): Array<Array<String>> {

        when {
           
            gameBoard[0][0] == "." -> {
                gameBoard[0][0] = "X"
            }
            else -> {
                println("There are no more spaces in this column")
            }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse 2D Array in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265260/parse-2d-array-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a simple replacement of your `when` statement

`gameBoard.findLast { it[0] == "." }?.set(0, "X") ?:  println("No spaces")`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to replace every occurrence inside of inner array you can do this:

```
    var gameBoard = Array(8) { Array(8) { "." } }
    val resultList: List<List<String>> = gameBoard.map { innerArray ->
        innerArray.map {
            if (it == ".") "X" else it
        }
    }
```

If you need to replace only first element (notice how `resultList` type changed):

```
    var gameBoard = Array(8) { Array(8) { "." } }
    val resultList: List<Array<String>> = gameBoard.map { innerArray ->
        val first = innerArray.first() // Expected that first element is present and not null
        innerArray.set(0, if (first == ".") "X" else first)
        innerArray
    }
```

If you need to save type `Array<Array<String>>` use `toTypedArray()` function:

```
    var gameBoard = Array(8) { Array(8) { "." } }
    gameBoard = gameBoard.map { innerArray ->
        innerArray.map {
            if (it == ".") "X" else it
        }.toTypedArray()
    }.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: These loops work but not for what I am looking for. I want to print only one x at a time. At the starting at the bottom of the Array.  These Print the whole column or entire Array.

Comment: Then your question is not clear because it is stated that you ".. want to check if the value in the double array equals "." and replace it with the user's input "X" or "O"" and not a word about printing something. I guess the issue you are talking here in comments is not related to the first-hand issue.

Comment: I stated starting from the bottom as in a connect four game. I will make sure to be more clear in my next question. I do appreciate the time you spent helping though. I'm sure ill use this in the future.

Comment: @Johnsonj39, you are welcome. For other people to help you the best way possible provide the best possible question. I'm not judging you by any means, but when I'm asking a question I personally think that it is better for me to spend 20-30 minutes more to make it as clear as specific as possible than for other 5-10 or more people spend 20-30 more minutes each figuring out what was it that I'm looking for. It saves ±100-300 minutes of cognitive time spent with no real benefit. The more detailed and clear your question is the more is the likelihood it will be answered. Again, you are welcome!

Comment: I ended up using this code for another area! Thanks, again